# camerini algorithm to find minimum bottleneck spanning tree, proof

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

I'm looking for a proof for camerini algorithm for finding MBST in undirected graph .
I couldn't find anywhere and I couldn't do it myself.
Thanks. 
[problem explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_bottleneck_spanning_tree)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22875799/how-to-compute-a-minimum-bottleneck-spanning-tree-in-linear-time

Comment: There is no proof there..